# TFS 2013 Queries for work item hierarchies with multiple levels

Tags: tfs

I have 3 entities (WorkItem Type) in TFS, This is the relationship between my entities:

```
[Release] 1------n [WorkOrder] n--------n [Bug]
```

I need to show Release and it's related WorkItems and related Bugs in one query (list).

I tried edit query and set it as `WorkItems and Direct Links` but it will show only one level of related Items.

I tried edit query and set it as `Tree of workitems` it works only for parent-child relations.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you verify that the statement below is correct?

All *WorkOrder* items are children to a parent *Release*.  *Bugs* are not directly linked to a *Release*, but are related to any number of *WorkOrders*.

Unfortunately it appears that you are correct.  For the time being there isn't a way to directly create the exact query you want that will show multiple Releases, all of the children WorkOrders, and all of the related Bugs in a single multi-level tree view.

I can think of two workarounds for you:

1. Remove the Release from the results and instead add a query parameter that targets specific releases.  Use the `Work Items and Direct Links` query option to query WorkOrders as the top-level work item and Related Bugs as the linked work items.  This will provide the data you want in the expected format (Bugs would collapse under Work Items).  If it's not for a report, your developers likely won't complain about having to key in a specific release.  Why would they want to query work items across multiple releases as part of their work?  If it *is* for a report, you could pull in multiple query results to Excel or another tool and format accordingly.
2. SQL Server Reporting Services should allow you to build filters for this, should you wish to build a report.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer your question:

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, unfortunately When you change your query to "Tree of work items" it will show only "Parent/Child" relation, which in my case relation between 'WorkOrder' and 'Bug' is not.

Comment: @RezaRahmati If the relation between a WorkOrder and a Bug is not a parent/child relationship, how are they linked in TFS?  My assumption based on your post was that, when viewing the Links for a WorkOrder, the user would see a Release linked as a parent and a Bug linked as a child.  If that indeed were the case, this answer should be correct.

Comment: @baultista The are join together by "Related" linktype